# How to create custom time zone in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I need a time zone which UTC+02:00 in winter time and switch to summer time (UTC+03:00) at first Sunday of March and switch back at first Sunday of November (the same as American DST rule).

All city I found in PostgreSQL database switch to UTC+03:00 at last Sunday of October and switch back UTC+02:00 at last Sunday of March

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL gets its time zone information from the [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), either the version installed on your operating system, or a private copy owned by PostgreSQL. Which one is used depends on how PostgreSQL was configured at build time (look for `--with-system-tzdata` in the output of `pg_config --configure`).

To add a new time zone, you'd have to modify that time zone database. [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) has an introduction to the format and the procedure.