# Postgres function now() returns incorrect time zone offset

Tags: postgresql, timezone

Recently Egypt changed its DST rules, and I have an issue with Postgres as the function `now()` is returning the wrong timezone.
My timezone is *Africa/Cairo* which is now `+3:00` but Postgres returns `+2:00`

```
select now();
```

Returns:

```
2023-05-05 22:17:06.461 +0200
```

Should be:

```
2023-05-05 23:17:06.461 +0300
```

My Postgres is containerized.
Time on the host: `Fri May  5 23:19:26 EEST 2023` (correct).
Time in the Postgres container: `Fri 05 May 2023 11:22:00 PM EEST` (correct).

`timezone` configuration is correct in Postgres:

```
show timezone;  -- returns Africa/Cairo
```

`timezone` table entry for 'Africa/Cairo' is +3:00:

```
select * from pg_timezone_names
where name = 'Africa/Cairo';`
```

Returns:

```
Africa/Cairo    EEST    03:00:00    true
```

Postgres version:

```
PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
```

I have no idea why now() is not working as expected.

Comment: What does `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` say?

Comment: exactly the same as now(), 2023-05-05 22:51:43.336 +0200

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver indeed, several times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the function `now()` is returning the wrong timezone.

Strictly speaking, the function `now()` (a.k.a `transaction_timestamp()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) does not "return a time zone" at all. The **display** of the `timestamptz` returned from `now()` is governed by the current `timezone` setting of the calling session - which, in turn, follows the rules laid down in the [IANA timezone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

In fairness, the Egyptian government re-introduced DST on a pretty short call. [According to Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egypt_Standard_Time)

> On 1 March 2023, the Egyptian Cabinet passed law 24 of 2023 to
> reinstate DST, moving to UTC+03:00 starting from the last Friday of
> April (28 April) at 00:01 until the last Thursday of October (26
> October) at 23:59.

<sub>And I am baffled that any country would bring back DST rules. The world should get rid of this actively harmful nonsense ASAP!</sub>

Postgres either uses its own copy or (more commonly) the time zone database of the underlying OS, if it was compiled with the option `--with-system-tzdata=DIRECTORY`.

That's the case in my local installation. I found out with [`pg_config --configure`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgconfig.html). My Postgres 15.2 has been compiled with the option `--with-system-tzdata=/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

Since my OS is up to date, with an update for `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Cairo` from mid-April, so are all my installed Postgres versions. I get summertime for 'Africa/Cairo' with the offset +03:00 for 2023 (but not for 2022).

I can reproduce your problem on dbfiddle.uk, which is not up to date, yet, either:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4-AtOARK)

(This may change any time.)

The only puzzling detail is that you see a correct entry in `pg_timezone_names`, like I do locally, but unlike the fiddle. (?)

**Why does it not work for you?**

I could see three possible reasons:

- Your version of Postgres wasn't compiled with `--with-system-tzdata=DIRECTORY`. Postgres 15.2 was released on 2023-02-09 and does not have the latest IANA patch, yet. (I would expect the next point release to include the update.)
- Your version of Postgres was compiled with `--with-system-tzdata=DIRECTORY`,
  but you didn't install OS updates (like you should).
- Something is lost in translation due to your containerized installation.

Related:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)
- [How to change utc_offset for timezone in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75999615/how-to-change-utc-offset-for-timezone-in-postgresql/75999702#75999702)
- [How to create custom time zone in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59941342/how-to-create-custom-time-zone-in-postgresql/59945877#59945877)

Comment: Firstly, Thanks a lot for taking the time to cleanup my post, i will make sure to enhance upcoming posts.

Comment: Secondly, I agree with all your points:
1- DST changes are pointless.
2- Egypt didn't give enough heads-up before DST rules change.

And finally, Same as you are, I am not getting how pg_timezone_names is correct while time functions do not respect it.
being a containerized DB, I don't have much control on the underlying OS, unless I built my own image. 

I guess I will have to wait until the issue resolves itself, the DB is used for my home lab, no pressure.

Thanks again!